# Someone pls explain me whats happening here

Tags: javascript

I have tried to using chrome debugger tool but not getting proper result.
*its output is (61, 16).
Unbale to understand it How its 61 and 16?*

```
    let a = 5, b = 15;  
    a += ++b + 7 + b++ + b--;
```

Comment: Are you aware of what ++ and -- do in JS? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

Comment: yes ++ is addition and -- substraction.

Comment: Then are you aware of the difference between `++b` and `b++`?

Comment: i thought both are same. but it dont looks same

Comment: Step through the expression cautiously, thinking about what operations have precedence and at what point(s) b actually gets changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JsNoob Here, variable values are changed by `post-increment` and `pre-increment`

Here, look at your code:

```
let a = 5, b = 15; //initial values

//in the second line of your code is...
 
1. (++b) is here `pre-increment` add 16 here and b value is 16 now.
2. As usual add 7
3. (b++) is here `post-increment` add 16 here and b value is 17 now.  
4. (b--) is here `post-decrement` add 17 here and b value is 16 now. 
5. += is sum and assignment operator.

now the result will be a = 5 + 16 + 7 + 16 + 17 (61)

result:

last value of a is : 61 
&
last value of b is: 16
```

Answer (score 1):

++b Before calculation add 1 in b and assing new value to b

b++ After Calculation add 1 in b and assing new value to b

b-- After Calculation Minus 1 from b and assing new value to b

a += ++b  means 5 + (1+15) = 21

21 +  7 = 28
28 + 16 = 44 but new value of b is 17

44 + 17 = 61, New value of b is 16

a = 61

b = 16

Comment: What the language are you using?

Comment: Thanks For The Answer. 

Answer (score 0):

If a = 5 and b = 15 then:

```
A + (b+1) + 7 + (b+1) + (b-1)
```

So basically:

```
A + 16 + 7 + 17 + 16
```

And you get 56.
But wait. A is already 5. And you're adding those numbers into A. So thus:

```
5 + 56 = 61
```

Remember when we added variable b twice and then subtracted it once?
(++b, b++, b--) That stays the same for b.

```
b + 2-1 (15 + 2 - 1)
b = 16
```

Comment: A + 16 + 7 + 17 {But why the 17 here, b value is 16 ? } + 16

Comment: When you incremented variable b by one you basically said 'b += 1'. Example:
A + (15+1) + 7 + (16+1). You added 1 into b before so now it will stay that way.

Comment: You have the last 2 numbers flipped in your explanation - it's `16 + 7 + 16 + 17` (check the values of the last 2 numbers). The first is `++b` which changes `b` to 16, and then uses it in the calculation. The third is `b++` which uses its previous value of 16, and then increments it to 17. The fourth is `b--` which uses its previous value of 17, then decrements it to 16. So you end up with `16 + 7 + 16 + 17` instead of `16 + 7 + 17 + 16`. You get the same result in the end, but the question is specifically asking how this is working, and I think your explanation is slightly incorrect.